# Answer consists of an image: what to do?

Tags: discussion

I have found an answer through the "Late answer" review queue, in which the answerer gave an answer by an image, nothing else. What to do now for this type of case?

[image]

[Find it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42900731/5153538)

Comment: Actually it's not an answer, it's a question posted as an answer. So for this specific case, flag it as NAA.

Comment: In any case answer as an image should be downvoted and deleted. Both because we are not going to click on some unidentified off-site links and because any such answer is 100% pure cr*p

Comment: @DavidArenburg: it's using the official Imgur account for the image, so it is not an unidentified off-site link. Low-rep users can't actually post images directly, only a link to the image. In principle a higher-rep user can easily fix this simply by adding a `!` to the image link. Sometimes an image *can* be the answer (but that's rare). If this wasn't actually a question instead, a NAA flag would be declined as an image that attempts to answer the question is still an attempt to answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters An image without any context/explanaion could be an answer but a very bad one. I didn't say "Flag as NAA", rather downvote/delete.

Comment: @DavidArenburg: you stated it should be deleted; I'm sorry, I indeed assumed you meant it should be deleted by moderator or review queue via the NAA flag.

Answer (score 46):

Generally speaking you have two options to begin with:

**Decision #1:**

- Click the link
- Do not click the link

If you do not want to click the link I'd suggest to down- and delete-vote the answer, as it - *in its current state* - bears little value.

---

**Decision #2:**

If you want to click the link, checking a few things is very important, as clicking links is often risky, to a certain extent atleast:

- You could possibly encounter content classified as NSFW
- You could get in trouble (i.e. if you're at work)
- **Is it worth it?**

If you - after considering the points mentioned above - aren't willing to click the link anymore, proceed as mentioned in **Decision #1**.

---

**Decision #3:**

If you're still willing to click the link, do so. Now you have to evaluate the content, and base your next action on the result of that.

- Is it an answer?
- Is the content worthy of being on Stack Overflow, and **worthy of your time?**

If only one or none of the two apply, don't bother. Proceed as mentioned in **Decision #1**. However, you could also simply downvote and comment in order to ask the author to improve his answer.

*Please note: If it's not worthy of being on Stack Overflow, and the image isn't on the official Stack Overflow Imgur I'd probably end up flagging it as VLQ, as most image hosters delete images after a while, and reuse those URLs.*

If both apply I'd suggest an edit, replacing the image with the content of the image. Explaining the changes will improve the chance of your edit being approved.

---

**TL;DR:**

Click the link if you're willing to risk it, otherwhise downvote + deletevote. If the content is an answer, worthy of being on Stack Overflow and not too extensive (*i.e. 100 lines of code*), edit it in replacing the image. Otherwhise downvote + deletevote, or downvote + comment asking the author to improve his answer.

---

*Disclaimer: I ab- and misused UML in order to create this, as I find Paint to be quite bad for tasks like this. I'm very sorry.*

**Visualized decision map:**

[image]

[Clean version (no memes)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3AKY.png)

Comment: Regarding the link at the bottom: What is the procedure for determining if I should click on a link to a picture describing the procedure for clicking on a link to a picture?

Comment: You forgot the usage of NAA flag in the process. A link somewhere doesn't count as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

In this case it is very easy since this is a link-only answer. Link-only answers are considered very low quality and should always get deleted. It doesn't matter where the link takes you or what it points at.

If they had posted the picture so that it would actually show on SO, then it would have been another story. Such an answer might be perfectly fine.